# Не могу найти ошибку в коде, помогите

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Что должно быть:
1. Js отправляет на php сервер информацию из переменной `$login`
2. Php подключает базу данных и получает значение пароля для этого логина из таблицы `accounts`
3. Если значение не найдено - php сервер отправляет `true`, если найден - `false`
4. Срабатывает определенный код в js, в зависимости от ответа сервера
Помогите найти ошибку

Js:

```
                            $.post('check.php', {'login':login},
                                function(data) {
                                    if(data == "true"){
                                        var div = document.querySelector("#login");
                                        div.className = "true";
                                        div.innerHTML = "Логин свободен!";
                                        alogin = null;
                                        alogin = true;
                                    }else if(data == "false"){
                                        var div = document.querySelector("#login");
                                        div.className = "false";
                                        div.innerHTML = "Логин занят!";
                                        alogin = null;
                                        alogin = false;
                                    }
                            });
```

Check.php

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
include ("db.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE login='$login'",$db);
if(empty($result)){
    echo("true");
}else{
    echo("false");
}
?>
```

Comment: А там есть ошибка?

Comment: Конечно, потому что данные базы данных я указал верно, все перепроверил, но ничего не работает, как ни странно, хотя в консоль тоже не идёт ничего, вот я и спрашиваю

Comment: Вы в вопросе не написали, что именно не работает. Сервер не получает запрос? Клиент не получает ответ от сервера? Клиент получает не тот ответ, который вы ожидали?

Comment: @ИванРепин вы отлаживали свой код? Проверяли чему равны `$login`, `$result`и `data`?

Comment: И надо избегать записей вида `login='$login'"` - потенциальное место для хака.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых надо экранировать переменные в "" то есть `login='{$login}'`, во-вторых этот код - потенциальная mysql injection, в-третьих `mysql_query` is deprecated since PHP 5.5, поэтому используйтн mysqli_query (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), в четвертых используйте явное сравнение результата:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM FROM accounts WHERE login='{$login}'");
if($result !== FALSE) {
   echo 1;
   die;
}
echo 2;
```

Но конечно правильнее всего было бы использовать PDO:

```
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */ $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1'; $user = 'dbuser'; $password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); } 
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM accounts
    WHERE login = ?');
$sth->execute(array($login));
$accounts = $sth->fetchAll();

if(!empty($accounts)) {
    echo 1;    
    die; 
}

echo 0;
```